# Best practise for Windows Service & Config Application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm about to write a small C# WPF service which references an XML file for its configuration. I have already written the WPF interface application which creates and maintains the XML which the service will read. A lot of code has gone into the classes used by the interface and I'd like to reuse them while only maintaining one version of code.

What is the best practise for maintaining two 'Main' entry points in Visual Studio? One for the application and the other for the service. Is it possible to mix a WPF forms and service project type?

How can I test and run the service before it is registered as a windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this correctly you have one UI project and you want to reuse the code in a separate Windows Service project.

Usually this is done by moving the common shared code into a separate project, called *Commons* or *Core*. This is what you need to unit-test. Finally, you add references from the UI and Windows service projects to this shared library.

```
/root
  ...
  /src
    /app
       /Core
       /Presentation  (ref to Core)
       /Service       (ref to Core)
    /test
       /Core.Test     (ref to Core)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Main so it has different behavior for debug configuration, and have your TestApp call into the public portions of MyService:

```
static void Main()
{
    #if DEBUG
        TestApp testApp = new TestApp();
        testApp.Run();
    #else
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new MyService() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    #endif
}
```

Then you can drive the logic of your service through the TestApp in the debugger without having to register the actual service.